# How to embed a GtkAboutDialog's content in a GtkNotebook widget

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, pygi

I'm writing a Python app that is tab-based, and I don't want it to have any additional pop-up dialogs.

I'd like to use the `Gtk.AboutDialog` functionality, but I don't want it to appear as a separate window. Rather, I'd like it to be embedded in one of the tabs of my `Gtk.Notebook` (which I've created with Glade).

I could not find any obvious way to do this. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: If this question is not specific to Ubuntu, then perhaps it should be migrated to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: The question is related to creating applications for Ubuntu, as are all those in the `application-development` tag. We recommend and encourage the use of Askubuntu as a resource for support for and by app developers http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move *content area* (`GtkVBox`) from `GtkDialog` to another `GtkContainer`, and then append to `GtkNotebook` - using **gtk.Widget.reparent()** method.

```
about = Gtk.AboutDialog()
about.set_program_name ("Application")
about.set_copyright ("Author")

box = Gtk.VBox ()
about.vbox.reparent (box)
notebook.append_page (box, Gtk.Label("About"))
about.destroy ()
```

With interface created in Glade, You must do simple trick for this solution. Create "About" tab in notebook with appended `GtkBox` (with id for example "about_box"). Then you can do something like this:

```
box = builder.get_object ("about_box")
about.vbox.reparent (box)
```

In some reasons Glade's `GtkAboutDialog` *content area* contains also `GtkButtonBox`. If You don't need this buttons simply destroy them:

```
about.action_area.destroy()
```

If You want only 'Credits' button, without 'Close' button, do something like this:

```
close_button = about.get_widget_for_response(Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
close_button.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, this does not seem to work, as it's not adding the tab apparently. I'm not sure whether it's due to the fact that I've initially created the notebook with Glade and then I try to add the tab in code. I haven't yet figured it out.

Comment: After testing it, I can confirm that the code above works for any `Gtk.Notebook` created in code, but if the notebook has been created with Glade, it won't get the new tab appended.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for following up! That works fine now.

Comment: One final question: I can get rid of the whole `action_area` widget, but is there a way to only get rid of the `close_button`? the box being now embedded in a tab makes the button unnecessary.